# how to pass data from the email template back to controller using mail::button component?

Tags: php, laravel

We are trying to pass an ID back to the controller from the email template. so how it works is a person will receive an email regarding an application along with 2 buttons to approve or reject the application. we want to allow the person to click on either buttons that will send back data to the controller indicating which button has been clicked. in this case, an ID back to the controller.

This is the mailable file:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SendEmailToCompany extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $content;
    public $attach;
    public $autoAttach;
    public $url;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($subject, $content, $autoAttachFile, array $files)
    {
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->content = $content;
        $this->attach = $files;
        $this->autoAttach = $autoAttachFile;
        $this->url = url('/companyApprove');
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {

        $files = $this->attach;
        $email = $this->markdown('email.emailToCompany');
        $email->attachFromStorage($this->autoAttach);

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $email->attach($file['path'],
            [
                'as' => $file['name'],
                'mime' => $file['type'],
            ]); //attach each file
        }
        return $email;
    }
}
```

Email template:

```
@component('mail::message')

# Support Letter

{{ $content }}

@component('mail::button', ['url'=> $url,  'color'=>'success'])
  Approved
@endcomponent

@endcomponent
```

DashboardController:

```
    public function companyApprove(Request $request)
    {
      $sID = request('studentID');
      dd($sID);

    }
```

web.php:

```php
Route::post('/companyApprove', 'DashboardController@companyApprove');
```

Comment: And what is your question? What doesn't work? Does `$this->url = url('/companyApprove');` contain the complete url to your server?

Comment: how to pass data from the email template back to controller using mail::button component?

Comment: Add a form and submit it to your server? Use a regular link instead of a button?

Comment: tried already but i have errors due to the csrf token

Comment: Then use a regular link and a GET route in your project. Or disable csrf for the route: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris